# counting checkbox and showing the value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am using the following jquery to show the selected number of checkboxes selected

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
        $("#count").text(count+ " item(s) selected");
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        var count = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
        $(this).val('check all');  
        $("#count").text(count+ " item(s) selected");
    })
})
```

here is the html

```
 <input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
 <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3

 <p id="count"></p>
```

When i check all it shows the right numbers, like 3 items selected and when i uncheck all, then it shows o items selected.

But when I remove individual selected checkbox then the count does not show up. like if i remove one, then the count will still be 3 and not the 2.

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Is the code exactly as you've put it in the question? As it appears not to work: http://jsfiddle.net/yDSBs/

Comment: working demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/CSBDS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the :checked pseudo-class:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
    $("#count").html($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
});
```

Comment: should i add this below my code within the dom ready function?

Comment: Yes, it will attach the click listener to all the checkboxes once the DOM is ready.

Comment: sorry, i tried yours and marked other answer as it had come up in your place, http://jsfiddle.net/sammry/y82Wz/

Answer (score 1):

try this code, check the [api](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) for more infomation

```
var countChecked = function() {
   var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
    $( "p" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
};
countChecked();
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CSBDS/)

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $('#count').text($("input:checkbox:checked").length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      if (this.checked) {
          count++;
      }
});
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function(){

      $('#count').html($( "input[type=checkbox]:checked" ).length);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is giving you the count:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
    $('#count').html($('input:checkbox:checked').size());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/7ZXTZ)

Comment: @sammry it is working all right. Tried clicking the CB-s on my fiddle? The checkall button is not in use in my sample code...